# Third Party Dashboard or Front-End

Tags: excel-2007, dashboard

I am trying to develop a proposal for small biz executives to have access to dashboards for up to date financials.
This data can come from various regional/local offices, to be collected and analyzed at the parent/home office.

***--*** Viewing Dashboard/Reports

**QUESTION** What is best way to display these reports?

a) Third Party?
b) Using Powerpoint?
c) Create a front-end?

Comment: Interesting question. However, [be warned](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that "5. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your database and how the "Parent office" stores the data I would seriously recommend using [Rocket Software CorVu NG](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-corvu-ng).

If you visit their page, there is a downloadable brochure for you to have a look at you can develop a professional  real time dashboard. I currently use them and have produced really professional looking and acting dashboards.

you can also embed the dashboard into web services to give you that extra edge.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is [this](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-corvu-ng) the product you recommend?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I use it on a day to day basis and I have got some great results from it, creating real time dashboards, scheduling reports to be sent internal and external recipients and i have just embedded a dashboard on the company's intranet site, all self taught so it is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do analysis of the data, then using Power Point is out of question, having said that, all depends of how much money and how much specificfy they want from the dashboards, if they want to spend little money, then you may want to look for a third party tool that's easy to use, like [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), otherwise, creating your own front end may be the way to go.